# HTML SVG reduce circle size

Tags: html, css, svg

I have found animated circle made with svg but I need to reduce the circle size

How can I modify the code please?

```css
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 816;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.progress-circle path {
  stroke-dasharray: 816;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash 2s linear;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<svg class="progress-circle" width="70" height="70">
  <path 
    d="m35,2.5c17.955803,0 32.5,14.544199 32.5,32.5c0,17.955803 -14.544197,32.5 -32.5,32.5c-17.955803,0 -32.5,-14.544197 -32.5,-32.5c0,-17.955801 14.544197,-32.5 32.5,-32.5z"
    stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```

Comment: if what you need is a smaller svg element you can add a `viewBox="0 0 70 70"` and change value of the width and height to what you need

Comment: 0) That's not actually drawing a circle. You can do that with the circle command. You're creating something that _looks_ like a circle. Eg: https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/bgBegJ

1) why not load the current figure into an svg editor and alter it to the desired size?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the width and height and then add the viewbox atrribute with the original size:

```css
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 816;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.progress-circle path {
  stroke-dasharray: 816;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: dash 2s linear;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<svg class="progress-circle" width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 70 70">
    <path
        d="m35,2.5c17.955803,0 32.5,14.544199 32.5,32.5c0,17.955803 -14.544197,32.5 -32.5,32.5c-17.955803,0 -32.5,-14.544197 -32.5,-32.5c0,-17.955801 14.544197,-32.5 32.5,-32.5z"
        stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `viewBox= "0 0 50 50"`  in `svg` tag and reduce `svg`width and height